# find $x^n +\cfrac{1}{x^n}$ in terms of $n$ given the following

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> If $\theta$ is a constant such that $0<\theta<\pi$ and
>   $x+\cfrac{1}{x}=2\cos \theta$ ,then for each positive integer $n$, find $x^n +\cfrac{1}{x^n}$ in terms of $n$ and $\theta$.

Frankly, I am kind of clueless of how to approach the problem.

One random thing I've tried was to solve the equation $x+1x−2y=0$ where $y=\cosθ$, and I've got as roots $x=\cosθ\pm i\sinθ$;this might be usefull but I can't see it now.

One thought: the expression $x^n +\cfrac{1}{x^n}=x^n\left(1+\cfrac{1}{x^{2n}}\right)$  might be involved with $e$ somehow?

I know my effort isn't really useful, but it was to show that I've tried something (as useless as it might be).

**Note:**  This exercise comes from the chapter "*complex numbers*" of my book.

Comment: There is a problem: if $x>0$ is a positive real number different from $1$, then $$x+ \frac{1}{x} > 2$$ so it cannot be equal to $2 \cos \theta$. The same for $x < 0$.

Comment: Square the equality to get the answer for $n=2$ and you might see a pattern.

Comment: $x=\cos(\theta)\pm\sin(\theta)$ are not the roots of $x+\frac{1}{x}-2\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: @Batominsky You're right,let me edit.

Comment: Yes, I think the roots are $x = \cos \theta \pm i \sin \theta$.  Hopefully this looks familiar from a particular "formula" in your textbook;  and once you figure out a nice way to write $x$, it should make it clearer what happens when you then take the quantity $x^n + x^{-n}$.

Comment: Damn,if it wasn't for that algebra mistake I would have figured...I shall be damned.(Thank you guys )

Comment: @Crostul not if $x$ is complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice, we have 
>   hence, $$x+\frac 1x=2\cos\theta$$$$\implies x^2-2x\cos \theta+1=0$$
>   Using quadratic formula, the roots are calculated as follows
>   $$x=\frac{-(-2\cos\theta)\pm\sqrt{(-2\cos \theta)^2-4(1)(1)}}{2(1)}=\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta$$
>
> substituting, $x=\cos\theta\pm i\sin \theta$, one should get
>
> $$\color{blue}{x^n+\frac 1{x^n}}=x^n+x^{-n}$$$$=(\cos \theta\pm i\sin \theta)^n+(\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta)^{-n}$$ Using de moivre's theorem,
>   $$=(\cos(n\theta)\pm i\sin(n\theta))+(\cos(n\theta)\mp i\sin(n\theta))$$ $$=\color{red}{2\cos(n\theta)}$$

Comment: This is mostly correct, but it assumes that $x$ can actually be written in the form $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.  (Which is true, but if I were a math teacher I'd want to see it shown explicitly.)

Comment: It would be good to show why $|r| = 1$.

Comment: $x=e^{i\theta}$ since:   $x^{2}-2\cos(\theta)x+1=0$ and $$x=\frac{2\cos(\theta)\mp\sqrt(4\cos^{2}(\theta)-4)}{2}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$.

Comment: Indeed,it would be nicer if you can show why we can let $x=cos \theta +i\sin \theta $.

Comment: Alright, just let $x=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ then substitute it in the given relation $$x+\frac{1}{x}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)+\frac{1}{r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}=2 \cos\theta$$ compare real & imaginary parts both the sides, you will get $|r|=1$ & $x=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$

Comment: This shows that $x = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ is _a_ solution to the equation.  It doesn't show that all possible solutions to the equation are of this form.  (But that's what the original question showed by solving the quadratic equation and getting $x = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, so it's really a minor quibble.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^n = x^n + \frac{1}{x^n} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} C_k\left(x^k + \frac{1}{x^k}\right)$$

For some coeficient $C_k$. So if you can express $\left(x^k + \frac{1}{x^k}\right)$ in terms of $k$ and $\theta$ for $k < n$ then you can do it for $n$ also.

Answer (score 2):

[Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) tells you that:

$$ cos \theta =\frac{e^{\imath \theta}+e^{-\imath \theta}}{2} = \frac{e^{\imath \theta}+\frac{1}{e^{\imath \theta}}}{2}\,. $$
So you nearly have your $x$ ($e^{\imath \theta}$ or $e^{-\imath \theta}$), and  $x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}$ should follow easily.

Answer (score 1):

By de moivre's theorem $(2cos\theta)^n=2\cos(n\theta)-2n\cos^{n-2}(\theta)$  and $x^n+(\frac{1}{x})^n=(\frac{x^2+1}{x})^n-(\sum {n\choose r}x^k.\frac{1}{x}^{n-k})$ .

Comment: Please re-check. There are some errors

Comment: I think i should subtract $2n\cos^{n-2}(\theta)$ is it right

Comment: Sorry add the term